# Typo3 multiple fields in Backend InputElement

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have question regarding the backend. I'm developing on Typo3 10.4, but also 9.5 and 11.5 so it doesn't really matter which version I'm using.

I created a new --div-- in the page config form and added a selectSingle inputElement.
The select's foreign_table is set to be_users.
It only shows the username of the backend user. Is there a way to also output the realName of each user shown in the list?

The only way I found to do so is to override the be_users.php and force alternative labels.
But I wonder if there is a way by telling the inputElement to get more than just the username. Like an "additional_fields" line in the 'config' part of the TCA.
Any ideas?

Comment: IMO, there is not an easy way. Maybe, you have a look at `itemsProcFunc` (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/ItemsProcFunc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I checked itemsProcFunc already but it would be even more tiresome to write a new function instead of just changing the TCA.
Maybe that would be a good feature for an update to the core.

Comment: For sure, it would be a nice feature. Feel free and open an issue/feature-request: https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues